# Dynamically Display Current Site Name in Content Editor Web Part

Tags: content-editor-web-part

I have been researching how to use the `SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site` reference to pull the current site name, but I am unsure how to call this in a content editor web part.  All I need is the site `"Title"` displayed, not the 
URL, with the end goal being to use CSS formatting to create (nearly) on the fly banners for any new sites.   I will be testing on SP 2007 but will ultimately be using on 2010, most likely linking web parts to .txt file to maintain formatting.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML='yourTitle'

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835634/add-site-title-to-page-using-cewp

to add the above javaScript:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML='yourTitle';

</script>
```

or use

```
<script>

document.write(document.all["onetidTitle"].innerText);

</script>
```

I dont know if im right I could be wrong but you could try the above and see if work which I think it should, sorry cant test it as I havent got acess to my sharepoint site! All you need to do is copy the code above and paste into the cewp.

http://sharepointsolutions.blogspot.co.uk/2007/07/adding-javascript-to-content-editor-web.html

http://www.ehow.com/how_10012230_use-javascript-sharepoint.html

**EDIT**

Ok, yes you are missing somthing ;) its not going to show anything as your not putting it into anything! all your doing is getting the title :) what you need to do to test it is encapsulate it with an alert to show you what it returns. For your case obviously you want it in a label to display within the cewp i presume. Please follow this guide first as its not great to add javascript straight into the cewp so you can do the following:

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/sharepoint-how-to-add-javascript-to.html

This way you can link to an external file that contains the javascript that you can edit properly in sharepoint designer or notepad++.

Now for the code :) try this for now in the cewp, I know this works as iv just tested it out:

```
alert(document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML);
```

.......ok so now I know its working what i did was create a label and added it to the page ;) like so...

```
var GetSiteTitle = document.createElement("span"); 

GetSiteTitle.id = "span1"; 

GetSiteTitle.className ="dynamicSpan"; 

GetSiteTitle.innerHTML =  document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;

document.body.appendChild(GetSiteTitle);
```

Now you need one last part as i stated at the top you need to add the Javascript tag like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 

var GetSiteTitle = document.createElement("span"); 

GetSiteTitle.id = "span1"; 

GetSiteTitle.className ="dynamicSpan"; 

GetSiteTitle.innerHTML =  document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;

document.body.appendChild(GetSiteTitle); 

</script>
```

Now this is working code that i know works as iv just tested it ;) hope you like it! just copy past the last section of code as its exactly what you want! Dont forget to follow the link to add the JS in a seperate file once you have tested on cewp. Otherwise youll be adding a version every time to the dom over and over again what really bad and would come into other problems :)

Ok tested again and this works 100%, before it was loading before the page loads causing an error, to solve this i just made it wait till the page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  

window.onload=func1;
 function func1() {
var GetSiteTitle = document.createElement("span");  

GetSiteTitle.id = "span1";  

GetSiteTitle.className ="dynamicSpan";  

GetSiteTitle.innerHTML =  document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML; 

document.body.appendChild(GetSiteTitle);  
 }

</script>
```

This should show up at the bottom half of the page but you can apply css to it using its class name dynamicSpan!

**Edit** Only show part of the title

To only show the second part of the title do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  

window.onload=func1;
 function func1() {

var GetSiteTitle = document.createElement("span");   

GetSiteTitle.id = "span1";   

GetSiteTitle.className ="dynamicSpan";   

var str= document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML;

var n=str.split("-");

GetSiteTitle.innerHTML = n[1] ;  

document.body.appendChild(GetSiteTitle); 
 }

</script>
```

If you want to show the first part of the title just change

> GetSiteTitle.innerHTML = n[1] ;

to

> GetSiteTitle.innerHTML = n[0] ;

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you but do I need a specific DocType declaration in order for this to work or a JavaScript tag or something else?  I still either get the code itself or nothing at all depending on what else I put in the source editor.

Comment: Iv changed the answer and hope it helps :)

Comment: I have attempted to use both the language/type javascript tags without any luck.  The code never returns anything to display? I have verified the site column is indeed called 'title'... Thank you for your help, do you think I need to use 'document.write' to display?  Or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Ok made changes and I hope you like it :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I was able to get the alert working on both 2007 and 2010 by file linking, so I know your code is functional... However there is probably something on the SharePoint admin side that is preventing this from displaying the site name... I have used JavaScript many times in CEWP's, so i'm baffled why this doesn't work.  I will have to discuss with the SP server admin about this.  But I am marking this question answered since I know your code is correct, thank you again!

Comment: glad you like it, iv edited it one more time! this time it will show up on the page and you just need to play around with the clss to get it where you want :)

Comment: I have this method working now and it is exactly what I was looking for, except when calling `document.getElementsByTagName('title')` it always prepends `Home -` to the site title.  Do you know of anyway to remove this so that just the site name displays?

Comment: hi check the last part edit that removes Home - or anything befor "-" and only shows anything after "-" :)

Comment: Works! Now I can easily recreate banners on new sites without editing the image! Thank You!

Comment: Hi Ali, I would like to show the SharePoint site name on a Document library upload form. The idea is to add a script editor web part on the Default library edit form and then using snippet there, I would like to display the current site name. Can you help, how do I achieve this?

Comment: You should ask it as a new question as this thread woould get too long and i would be happy to help!